# material design drawer issue

Tags: css, sass, material-design, mdc-components

i have a codepen in which there is a dismissible drawer with top app bar component 
which on resizing to 598px width the top app bar width decreases from 64px to 56px
but when using @media query to align it the drawer is not aligning please can you give a solution to this

codepen >>> https://codepen.io/BhavyaSingh2003/pen/NJbGoO

```
 @media all and (max-width: 599px) {
 .mdc-drawer--dismissible {
   top: 56px;
   height: calc(100% - 56px);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This CSS declaration:

```
.app-drawer-layout .mdc-drawer--dismissible
```

has more [specificity (weight)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than just:

```
.mdc-drawer--dismissible
```

So you can either write selector with the same specificity:

```
@media all and (max-width: 599px) {
  .app-drawer-layout .mdc-drawer--dismissible {
    top: 56px;
    height: calc(100% - 56px);
  }
}
```

...or add `!important` to your CSS:

```
@media all and (max-width: 599px) {
  .mdc-drawer--dismissible {
    top: 56px !important;
    height: calc(100% - 56px) !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks rusten gareev by the way the pen was fork of your pen on codepen you make nice material design pens.

Comment: Just noticed it! Thanks! I will surely continue to make code pens about MDC Web. You can ask me about any further questions!

Comment: @rusteemgareev can you please delete this answer or upvote the question cause -1 doesnt looks nice on my profile